# How to create 5 new columns reflecting past 5 transactions of each customer?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

Basically task is that for every customer last 5 transactions should show up but it should be on basis of that customer only.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "customer_id": [121,121,121,121,121,121,121,233,233,233,233,233,233,233,233],
    "Amount": [500,300,400,239,568,243,764,890,456,420,438,234,476,568,243,]
})
```

So, I am trying to create 5 new columns based on shift of "Amount" column.

For this below code works well

```
for obs in range(1,6):
    df['S_'+ str(obs)] = df.Amount.shift(obs)
```

**output:**

```
    customer_id  Amount    S_1    S_2    S_3    S_4    S_5
0           121     500    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
1           121     300  500.0    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
2           121     400  300.0  500.0    NaN    NaN    NaN
3           121     239  400.0  300.0  500.0    NaN    NaN
4           121     568  239.0  400.0  300.0  500.0    NaN
5           121     243  568.0  239.0  400.0  300.0  500.0
6           121     764  243.0  568.0  239.0  400.0  300.0
7           233     890  764.0  243.0  568.0  239.0  400.0
8           233     456  890.0  764.0  243.0  568.0  239.0
9           233     420  456.0  890.0  764.0  243.0  568.0
10          233     438  420.0  456.0  890.0  764.0  243.0
11          233     234  438.0  420.0  456.0  890.0  764.0
12          233     476  234.0  438.0  420.0  456.0  890.0
13          233     568  476.0  234.0  438.0  420.0  456.0
14          233     243  568.0  476.0  234.0  438.0  420.0
```

**Problem**

By this method the next customer in index number 7 is also showing previous customers transactions which is wrong. It should be NaN

I think I need to group on the basis of customer_id and then get shift of the amount for each customer

And I am not able to do that.

Comment: Consider using pivot table (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html#pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table)

Comment: sidenote: congrats on writing a really well structured question, well done

Comment: @Erfan agreed! from the short snippet to create the `df`, through the self attempt and the output, to the bold titles. I wish all questions were asked like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use groupby when shifting:

```
for obs in range(1,6):
    df['S_'+ str(obs)] = df.groupby(["customer_id"]).Amount.shift(obs)
```

which results in

```
    customer_id  Amount    S_1    S_2    S_3    S_4    S_5
0           121     500    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
1           121     300  500.0    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
2           121     400  300.0  500.0    NaN    NaN    NaN
3           121     239  400.0  300.0  500.0    NaN    NaN
4           121     568  239.0  400.0  300.0  500.0    NaN
5           121     243  568.0  239.0  400.0  300.0  500.0
6           121     764  243.0  568.0  239.0  400.0  300.0
7           233     890    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
8           233     456  890.0    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
9           233     420  456.0  890.0    NaN    NaN    NaN
10          233     438  420.0  456.0  890.0    NaN    NaN
11          233     234  438.0  420.0  456.0  890.0    NaN
12          233     476  234.0  438.0  420.0  456.0  890.0
13          233     568  476.0  234.0  438.0  420.0  456.0
14          233     243  568.0  476.0  234.0  438.0  420.0
```

Comment: Thanks @Paul for providing such simple solution

Comment: Thanks @Paul for providing such simple solution

Comment: @Erfan I accepted both as I assumed that we should accept all the answers that works. Since both were giving me right results so I marked on both, I didn't know we should select only the better one. I have corrected that mistake now. Thanks for letting me know!!

Answer (score 2):

you can use [`.groupby` and then `.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) with your own logic, like this:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "customer_id": [121, 121, 121, 121, 121, 121, 121, 233, 233, 233, 233, 233, 233, 233, 233],
    "Amount": [500, 300, 400, 239, 568, 243, 764, 890, 456, 420, 438, 234, 476, 568, 243]
})


def add_S_cols(df):
    for obs in range(1, 6):
        df['S_' + str(obs)] = df.Amount.shift(obs)
    return df


print(df.groupby("customer_id").apply(add_S_cols))
```

Output:

```
    Amount  customer_id    S_1    S_2    S_3    S_4    S_5
0      500          121    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
1      300          121  500.0    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
2      400          121  300.0  500.0    NaN    NaN    NaN
3      239          121  400.0  300.0  500.0    NaN    NaN
4      568          121  239.0  400.0  300.0  500.0    NaN
5      243          121  568.0  239.0  400.0  300.0  500.0
6      764          121  243.0  568.0  239.0  400.0  300.0
7      890          233    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
8      456          233  890.0    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
9      420          233  456.0  890.0    NaN    NaN    NaN
10     438          233  420.0  456.0  890.0    NaN    NaN
11     234          233  438.0  420.0  456.0  890.0    NaN
12     476          233  234.0  438.0  420.0  456.0  890.0
13     568          233  476.0  234.0  438.0  420.0  456.0
14     243          233  568.0  476.0  234.0  438.0  420.0
```

Comment: Yes this works perfectly, thanks for writing the solution in detail @Adam.Er8